# com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 400

Tags: scala, paypal-sandbox

Am implementing the paypal-rest-api call using scala.
Am having the working example in java.

But getting "Unknown error" from paypal sandbox api, when implementing the same in scala.

Here is the code.

```
class DirectPayment {

    def pay(): Unit = {
    val payment = new Payment
    val accessToken = AccessTokenGenerator.getAccessToken()
    val apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken)
    try {      


        val amount = new Amount
        amount.setCurrency("USD")
        amount.setTotal("12")

        val transaction = new Transaction
        transaction.setDescription("creating a direct payment with credit card");
        transaction.setAmount(amount);


        val transactions = new java.util.ArrayList[Transaction]
        transactions.add(transaction)

        val creditCard = new CreditCard
        creditCard.setType("visa")
        creditCard.setNumber("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        creditCard.setExpireMonth(12)
        creditCard.setExpireYear(2020)
        creditCard.setCvv2("874")
        creditCard.setFirstName("xxxx")
        creditCard.setLastName("xxxxxxx")

        val billingAddress = new Address
        billingAddress.setLine1("111 First Street")
        billingAddress.setCity("Saratoga")
        billingAddress.setState("CA")
        billingAddress.setPostalCode("95070")
        billingAddress.setCountryCode("US")

        val fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument
        fundingInstrument.setCreditCard(creditCard)

        val fundingInstrumentList = new ArrayList[FundingInstrument]()
        fundingInstrumentList.add(fundingInstrument)

        val payer = new Payer
        payer.setFundingInstruments(fundingInstrumentList)
        payer.setPaymentMethod("credit_card")   

        payment.setIntent("sale")
        payment.setPayer(payer)
        payment.setTransactions(transactions)

        val sdkConfig = new HashMap[String, String]()
        sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox")

        val requestId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        val apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken, requestId);
        apiContext.setConfigurationMap(sdkConfig)
        println("apiContext" + apiContext)
        val createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext)
        //exception occurs here          

    println(Payment.getLastResponse())

    println(String.format("created payment with id [%s] and status=[%s]", createdPayment.getId(), createdPayment.getState()))

   } catch {
 case e: PayPalRESTException => {
   println("EXCEPTION IN DO FINAL PAYMENT METHOD")
   val msg = e.getMessage
   println(e)
   println(msg)
 }   
 }

}
```

having this in buil.sbt

```
 libraryDependencies += "com.paypal.sdk" % "paypal-core" % "1.5.2"
 libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
 libraryDependencies += "com.paypal.sdk" % "rest-api-sdk" % "0.7.0"
```

Comment: please could you explain a little more what is happening to you. Maybe if you are consuming your app through HTTP call or something like that.

Comment: Thank you @salc2. It is a standalone scala code. I found what i missed. missed to add creditCard.setBillingAddress(billingAddress), before adding it to the fundingInstruments. Got fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missed to add

```
    creditCard.setBillingAddress(billingAddress)
```

before adding it to the fundingInstruments. Got fixed now.