# scala java paypal-sdk cant construct valid Transaction

Tags: java, scala, paypal-rest-sdk

I am struggeling with a strange problem or maybe just my own stupidity. What puzzles me most that logically i do the same as in this post: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493831/com-paypal-core-rest-paypalrestexception-error-code-400) . My code looks like this:

```
def createPayment(products: List[Product], company: Company, user: User):   Either[Payment, String] = {
if (products.nonEmpty) {
  val guid = UUID.randomUUID().toString.replaceAll("-", "")
  val redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls
  redirectUrls.setReturnUrl("https://myurl/#/paysuccess?guid=" + guid)
  redirectUrls.setCancelUrl("https://myurl/#/payfail?guid=" + guid)
  val payer = new Payer
  payer.setPaymentMethod("paypal")
  val itemList = new ItemList
  val items = new util.ArrayList[Item]
  var total = 0.0
  var vat = 0.0
  products.foreach {
    product =>
      logger.info("Product: " + product)
      var price = ""
      if (product.isDeal.get && !product.validto.get.before(new Date())) {
        total += product.oldPrice.get
        vat += product.vat.get
        price = product.oldPrice.get.toString
      } else {
        total += product.price.get
        vat += product.vat.get
        price = product.price.get.toString
      }
      val item = new Item
      item.setName(product.name.get)
      item.setCurrency("EUR")
      item.setPrice(price)
      item.setQuantity("1")
      item.setTax(product.vat.get.toString)
      item.setDescription(product.shortInfo.get)
      logger.info("Item: " + item)
      items.add(item)

  itemList.setItems(items)

  val details = new Details
  details.setShipping("0")
  details.setTax(vat.toString)
  val amount = new Amount
  amount.setCurrency("EUR")
  amount.setTotal(total.toString)
  amount.setDetails(details)
  val transaction = new Transaction
  logger.info("NewTrans: " + transaction)

  transaction.setAmount(amount)
  //transaction.setItemList(itemList)
  transaction.setDescription("Thank you for your order")
  logger.info("FinishedTrans: " + transaction)

  val transactions = new java.util.ArrayList[Transaction]
  logger.info("NewTransList: " + transactions)
  transactions.add(transaction)
  logger.info("FinishedTransList: " + transactions)
  val order = new Payment()
  order.setIntent("sale")
  order.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls)
  order.setPayer(payer)
  order.setTransactions(transactions)
  order.setNoteToPayer(guid)
  logger.info("Order : " + order)
  try {
    val createdOrder = order.create(accessToken)
    Order.setSale(createdOrder, guid, company, user, products)
    Left(createdOrder)
  } catch {
    case e: PayPalRESTException =>
      logger.error("PayPalRESTException " + e.getMessage)
      Right(e.getMessage)
  }
}
else {
  logger.error("No Products found")
  Right("No Products found")
}
}
```

Now what happens is that:

```
 transaction = new Transaction
```

logs to:

```
transactions : []
```

when I call:

```
transaction.setAmount(amount)
```

it logs to:

```
{
"transactions": [],
"amount": {
"currency": "EUR",
"total": "49.99",
"details": {
  "shipping": "0",
  "tax": "7.98"
}
```

And Paypal of course say that this format isnt correct. Because there should not be a transactions : [] in the transaction Arraylist. In the link above the transaction object is created exactly the same and it seams to work, for me it doesnt. Does anyone have a clue why. When looking at the constructor in Transaction.java it states:

```
public Transaction() {
    transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
}
```

What completly puzzles me is that from looking at the code the results i get in the logs are correct. But then the code should not work because it is not possible to construct a valid transaction with:

```
val amount = new Amount
amount.setCurrency("EUR")
amount.setTotal(total.toString)
val transaction = new Transaction
transaction.setAmount(amount)
transaction.setDescription("Thank you for your order")
val transactions = new java.util.ArrayList[Transaction]
transactions.add(transaction)
val order = new Payment()
order.setTransactions(transactions)
```

that logs to:

```
Order : {"intent": "sale",
         "payer": {"payment_method": "paypal"},
         "transactions": [{"transactions": [],
                           "amount": {"currency": "USD",
                           "total": "12"},
                           "description": "Thank you for your order"
                           }],
         "note_to_payer": "26c4efcad7c44e0ebf2d0fa5344f22a0",
         "redirect_urls": {
              "return_url": "https://mydomain/#/paysuccess?guid\u003d26c4efcad7c44e0ebf2d0fa5344f22a0",
              "cancel_url": "https://mydomain/#/payfail?guid\u003d26c4efcad7c44e0ebf2d0fa5344f22a0"
               }
}
```

This Payment object is correctly rejected by paypal stating that:

> ERROR - PayPalRESTException Response code: 400  Error response: {"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].item_list.items[0].tax","issue":             "Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands separator ',', limited to 7 d             igits before the decimal point and currency which is a valid ISO Currency Code"},{"field":"transactions","issue":"Item currency codes should be same as the tran             saction currency code in all buckets"},{"field":"transactions[0].item_list.items[0].currency","issue":"Required field missing"},{"field":"transactions[0].item_l             ist.items[0].price","issue":"Currency amount must be non-negative number, may optionally contain exactly 2 decimal places separated by '.', optional thousands s             eparator ',', limited to 7 digits before the decimal point and currency which is a valid ISO Currency Code"}],"message":"Invalid request - see details","informa             tion_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#VALIDATION_ERROR","debug_id":"912e594c547b7"}

witch I intpret as paypal telling me that my first entry in transaction is not valid.

Does anyone have a clue whats going on ?

Comment: solved the problem was NOT additional transactionsArray in TransactionObject but the itemsList + amount.details

Comment: self-answer or delete question to avoid "unanswered" status please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See above there wast a problem with lib code